# Log in immediately following successful fingerprint scan, rather than having to hit button

Tags: 15.10, login-screen, fingerprint-reader

is it possible to login immediately upon a valid scan rather than hitting the login button first? (similar to how Windows works in this regard)

Using ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Strangely I am using 15.10 (on Thinkpad) and I don't have to hit any button: 1) I press CTRL+ALT+L to lock my session 2) I swipe my right index 3) My desktop shows up immediately. What is your hardware?

Comment: yes locking the session then using fingerprinrt to unlock works fine (although it very quickly times outs waiting for fingerprint login and reverts to password field, but I have a separate question now for that issue).
It is on initial login after boot that a login button appears after a valid swipe. I must press this button to actually complete the fingerprint login

Comment: Ah yes I think I have this problem at reboot too! *(I only rebooted once since I installed on my new Thinkpad so I didn't remember that right away)* Would you mind adding these details to the question's body, as comments get deleted often? Thanks!